# Large data transfer between two python scripts

Tags: python, sockets

I have a 'read' python script which reads large amounts of data and process it. This data has to be supplied to multiple 'function' python scripts, which I want to run in parallel. This data contains multiple list variables. I want to run all these python scripts (both read and function) through a single shell script.

What is the efficient way of transferring large data from the 'read' script to multiple 'function' scripts?

I have looked at the following options so far:

1. Transfer through sockets, with json or pickle to transfer lists.
2. Simply write the processed data into a new file, and read this file in each of the 'function' scripts.
3. [Lightweight Communication and Marshalling](https://lcm-proj.github.io) LCM. I had issues while running this.

Which of these methods is best? or suggest any new methods. Also, help to setup LCM will be appreciated.

Comment: If the data is provided to you in JSON format then you **might** be able to get data using REST service. Additionally, you should consider developing a sample code. It will allow you to identify a specific area to improve. This problem can be viewed as producer-consumer problem which can be solved using Apache Kafka.

Comment: You are not transferring across network. So pipe/fifo should be better then socket. Also did you checked `https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html`.

Comment: @TrishanshBhardwaj Thanks! Is it faster than socket? And can I use it for transferring lists?

Comment: Why don't you try which one is fastest?

Comment: If you want help with LCM, I'd recommend a separate question in which you show what you've tried and describe how exactly it failed.

Comment: @user9795751 As per my understanding, pipe and fifo should be faster then socket. You can confirm by benchmarking. Both Socket and pipe transfers binary data, so you have to serialize python data types.

Comment: @TrishanshBhardwaj Thanks! I tried pipe, it was faster than reading from files.